# AFNetworking with Anchor in URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, afnetworking-2

Trying to load a webpage into a UIWebView with AFNetworking.
The URL of the webpage looks like in this example www.something.com/test#!info/c1fd.
Instead of presenting the content of this URL, the UIWebView always displays the content of www.something.com. Is this the wrong approach?

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.something.com/test#!info/c1fd"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        [myWebView loadData:responseObject MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL string you pass to `URLWithString:` is not properly encoded. You need to escape the `!` and the `#` as follows:

```
@"www.something.com/test%23%21info/c1fd"
```

Per the docs:

> This method expects URLString to contain only characters that are
>   allowed in a properly formed URL. All other characters must be
>   properly percent escaped. Any percent-escaped characters are
>   interpreted using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I have tested this but this is not working at all. If I call this URL like you wrote the content is not found at all.